# Parse.com: Can we prevent android from creating new installation records when an updated app is installed?

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I am working with parse push notification in android. I am facing a problem .

I install the app on a mobile device an installation record is created in the installation table. Than i uninstall the current app and re install it again. a new installation record is created. So now i send the notification on the devices.

So on how many installation record(registered devices) notification will send?

If notification is send on two records than one notification sent is useless, because the app registered with this record is un-installed.

So how to remove the previous record from installation when i re-install the app.

iOS is not creating new installation records, but android is.

Comment: The installationId is unique to each device. So you can query for existing records with your installationId. This way you can delete them or not creating  a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Parse doesn't count the push targeted to uninstalled devices. So don't worry about that. It is dead already. I guess there is no way of removing an installation though.

Answer (score 0):

There is ways to remove unused installations. You can use a Cloud code to do so, here is an example: [Here](https://gist.github.com/mbmc/ebe5b65bc4eb86904c78)

There is more people asking similar questions, take a look: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084043/clean-up-parse-data-after-app-uninstall)

When you install an App on a Apple Device it uses the same deviceId, this is an Apple feature.

When you install an App on an Android Device it creates a deviceId, if you uninstall and install again it will create another devideId (Why? I don't know. You can find more info: [Here](https://www.parse.com/questions/unsubscribe-problem-related-to-app-uninstall))

Finally, there is someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888262/delete-duplicate-installation-on-android-parse-com) that apparently solved this problem with android using cloud code.

Another solution is to search for inactive users during a period them delete their installations. I suggest to delete an installation after 90 days without use.