# Delete duplicate installation on android parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying delete duplicate installation when reinstall on android. 
I'm doing get query from ParseInstallation but it is not working.

I attach my code below:

```
public boolean checkDuplicate(String id, ParseInstallation installation){




    ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("userId", id);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseInstallation>() {
        public void done(List<ParseInstallation> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                //Log.d("LISTA-CHECKDUPLICATE", "id " + list.size() );
                for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
                    try {
                        list.get(i).delete();
                    } catch (ParseException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } else {
                Log.d("LISTA-CHECKDUPLICATE", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });


    return false;

}
```

Comment: What specific behavior are you seeing that's incorrect?

Comment: Doesn't get anything

Comment: You can not do find operation installation table. you will get the exception with following msg "Clients aren't allowed to perform the find operation on the installation collection."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved this with cloud code and calling this function on android:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("checkDuplicado", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    var objectId = request.params.objectId;
    query.equalTo("userId", request.params.userId);
    query.first().then(function(duplicate) {
        if (typeof duplicate === "undefined" ) {
            console.log("Duplicate does not exist,New installation");
            response.success("Nueva Instalacion");
        } else if(duplicate.id != objectId){
            console.log("Duplicado existe..Intentando borrar " + duplicate.id );
            //console.log("userId-NUEVO " + request.object.get("userId") + " ID: " + request.object.id);
           // console.log("userId-DUPLICADO " + duplicate.get("userId") + " ID: "+ duplicate.id);
            duplicate.destroy().then(function(duplicate) {
                console.log("Duplicado borrado correctamente");
                response.success("Duplicado borrado correctamente");
            }, function() {
                console.log(error.code + " " + error.message);
                response.success("Error Borrando duplicado");
            });

           response.success("Check duplicados realizado correctamente");
        }
        else{
            response.success("Check duplicados realizado correctamente");
        }
    }, function(error) {
        console.warn(error.code + error.message);
        response.success("Error");
    });
    });
```

Comment: Hwy, after using this, I was able to delete the installation. But with it, My channel list has gone. How to copy Channel list to new installation before deleting old one?

Comment: This means you can only have one user per device right?

Comment: yes I have only user per device. and Palak Darji you can copy the channel before delete, read the row and copy the value.